# Font Awsome min causing mixed mode issues

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Inside my theme font awsome is being referenced like this in fontawsome.min. The problem with this is its causing mixed mode issues with my site as the font is not being served up with https.

How do I replace the font-awsome.min with one that will pull down the font securly.

You can see the site here https://styleloftno.co.uk

```
 */@font-face{font-family:'FontAwesome';src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.6.3');src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.6.3') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3') format('woff2'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.6.3') format('woff'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.6.3') format('truetype'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.6.3#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');font-weight:normal;font-style:normal}.fa{display:inline-block;font:normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;font-size:inherit;text-rendering:auto;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale}.fa-lg{font-size:1.33333333em;line-height:.75em;vertical-align:-15%}.fa-2x{font-size:2em}.fa-3x{font-size:3em}.fa-4x{font-size:4em}.fa-5x{font-size:5em}.fa-fw{width:1.28571429em;text-align:center}.fa-ul{padding-left:0;margin-left:2.14285714em;list-style-type:none}.fa-ul>li{position:relative}.fa-li{position:absolute;left:-2.14285714em;wi...
```

Comment: The link you provided is dead.

Comment: Why not just find a CDN that serves it over HTTPS?

Comment: The font itself is loaded from the same host and with the same protocol as the above CSS, so the issue is where is that CSS located, and how is it loaded?